# Difference between printf() and writeln() in D

Tags: d

What is the difference between `printf("Hello, world!")` and `writeln("Hello, world!")` in the D programming language?

I noticed that `writeln()` breaks at the end by it self, while `printf()` does not. Is that the only difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`printf` is calling the C function and thus works by C typing rules. Notably, you must get the format string right or you will get nonsense. For example, passing an `int` when you specified `%s` instead of `%d` will likely crash your program.

`writef` in D is aware of the types you pass and will thus automatically do the right thing in most cases, or throw an exception when it is impossible instead of corrupting your memory.

`writefln` is `writef` that automatically adds a new line to the end too.

Comment: Would you recommend to always use writeln/writef then, considering it's easier to use (the less you know exactly what you do)?

Comment: Yes, you should always use `writefln`/`writef`.

Comment: You should not use any C functions that are available as a D port within Phobos and/or another library, unless necessary for certain optimization, because of already existing implementation, but usually you should always go with the D standard library and/or any other libraries available with the functionality you need.

Comment: I actually don't agree with that, there's a lot of places where the C function is perfectly great and you shouldn't be afraid of them. A lot of people worry that D doesn't have as many libraries because they are afraid of using perfectly good C functions. But you *should* understand them  so you know to use them properly. writef is better in almost every way than printf (the two advantages are it compiles a wee bit faster and takes less space in the executable), but that isn't true of all wrapped functions.

Answer (score 2):

`printf`, like in C, accepts a format string. (ex. `printf("number = %d", 123)` prints "number = 123")

`writeln` will convert each argument to a string and print them one after the other, and then print a newline. (ex. `writeln("number = ", 123)` prints "number = 123")

Comment: Oh yes, this is important too! writefln and writeln are different - the f version uses the format string, the plain writeln does not - it works like you said!